# Custom back stacks for Android Fragments Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

How one would go about creating custom back stack behavior for each Tab such as in the FragmentTabs sample ? The parent Activity's FragmentManager seems to be very strict in managing a single stack, yet I've seen comments in SO stating that such behavior is possible in Apps such as Browsers, where each tab/window has its own back key management.
I am trying to avoid the ActivityGroup / TabActivity route.

Comment: I downloaded the ICS's browser source code to check how they do it, looks like they override the onKeyUp event manually to handle back button behavior, not using fragment transactions at all. Would it be possible to have multiple FragmentManagers, one for each tab/section ? Then I would add/replace to the "active" manager and handle back press towards each one too.

Comment: Having multiple `FragmentManagers` would mean you'd have multiple `Activity`s... one for each tab, which (according to Dianne Hackborn, a.k.a. hackbod) is not the best solution. At some point someone is going to have to implement this behavior eventually...